# generation of a view based on comma seperated values in transaction table

Tags: sql-server

how to generate a view to display records with masters data based on comma separated values of a transaction table

am getting the required result in management studio, using

```
select * from masters_view where parameter1 in (x,y) and parameter2 in (r,s,t)
```

the values (x,y) and (r,s,t) are available as a record in another table as nvarchar

Comment: A view can't contain dynamic SQL, which is usually required to convert a string to column references. Why are your column references stored in an `nvarchar` column? Why does this need to be a view? Do you want the view to reference these columns in the other table dynamically, or do you want code to create a view based on the values in the table right now, and the view will always have those values hard-coded until you alter/re-create it, even if the other table's data changes in the meantime?

Comment: territories, product codes and pack sizes handled by executives are saved for each executive id in a transaction table. The view is dynamic and not for static values (based on data now) as records would be inserted / updated over course of time in the transaction table

Comment: Well you're not going to be able to do that very easily with a view, and even if you could do so easily, performance would likely suffer. Can you explain why this needs to be a "dynamic view"?

Comment: is it not as simple as building a set of 6 select statements based on my above example and outputting the same ?

would make my life a lot easier to handle the forms and reports, with this view in place

Comment: No, it is not as simple as that. Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: when I manually do the same in management studio, I got the required output

Comment: When you manually do WHAT the same? If you hard-code the values like you did in your question? Well of course THAT works. Now try writing a query - without dynamic SQL - that actively pulls those column references from your other table. Let us know how far you get.

Comment: thanks for the support Aaron :)

found a way using a function, as explained here
http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2000.html#iterative